# Running a function 100 times

Tags: r, function, loops

`a` is my data.frame. 
How can I run the `Zi_hat` function 100 times by updating the value of  `pi_hat`, `theta_hat`, `lambda_hat`? And each time show the result for `pi_hat`, `theta_hat`, `lambda_hat`

```
Zi <- function(x){
  x <- zi_hat=(pi_hat*theta_hat*exp(-theta_hat*a))/(pi_hat*theta_hat*exp(-theta_hat*a)+(1-pi_hat)*lambda_hat*exp(-lambda_hat*a))


  pi_hat=(1/n)*sum(zi_hat)
  theta_hat=sum(zi_hat)/(sum(zi_hat*a))
  lambda_hat=(n*sum(zi_hat))/(n*sum(a)-sum(zi_hat)*sum(a))

  c(pi_hat,theta_hat,lambda_hat)  #print out the updated data#
  if (?>100) break
}
```

for the "?"
Should I add another statement in the function to make make?

Comment: have a look at `for`-loops or `while`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this

```
Zi <- function(x){
counter = 1
while(counter <= 100)
{
  x <- zi_hat=(pi_hat*theta_hat*exp(-theta_hat*a))/(pi_hat*theta_hat*exp(-theta_hat*a)+(1-pi_hat)*lambda_hat*exp(-lambda_hat*a))
  pi_hat=(1/n)*sum(zi_hat)
  theta_hat=sum(zi_hat)/(sum(zi_hat*a))
  lambda_hat=(n*sum(zi_hat))/(n*sum(a)-sum(zi_hat)*sum(a))
  c(pi_hat,theta_hat,lambda_hat)  #print out the updated data#

  counter = counter + 1
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @cccmir. Very nice example. 
 It have to return zi, pi_hat, lambda_hat, and theta_hat separately.

```
Zi <- function(pi_hat,theta_hat,lambda_hat){
  counter = 1
  while(counter <= 10000)
  {
    zi_hat<-(pi_hat*theta_hat*exp(-theta_hat*a))/(pi_hat*theta_hat*exp(-theta_hat*a)+(1-pi_hat)*lambda_hat*exp(-lambda_hat*a))
    pi_hat=(1/n)*sum(zi_hat)
    theta_hat=sum(zi_hat)/(sum(zi_hat*a))
    lambda_hat=(n*sum(zi_hat))/
    (n*sum(a)-sum(zi_hat)*sum(a))
    counter = counter + 1
  }
  return(lambda_hat)
}
```